# How to get value based on group key using MAP

Tags: java

I want to fetch these numbers according to their related key.

```
AD-PIN-CISCO-SIP    PHNO        en_US   80719991
AD-PIN-CISCO-SIP    PHNO-PUD    en_US   90719903
AD-PIN-CISCO-SIP    PHNO-PUS    en_US   90719900
AD-PIN-CISCO-SIP    PHNO-QAS    en_US   80719900
AD-PIN-CISCO-SIP    PHNO-QCS    en_US   90719902
AD-PIN-CISCO-SIP    PHNO-TUS    en_US   80719900
```

I am going with this code, need a perfect approach.

```
public static String getCiscoSipPhNo()
{

    Map skillsValueMap =ValidFieldValuesUtil.getValueMap(ADPinEntryAppConstants.AD_PIN_ENTRY_APP_KEY);
    {
        Set<String> keySet = skillsValueMap .keySet();
        for ( String fldKey : keySet)
        {
            if(fldKey!= null && fldKey.equalsIgnoreCase("")
                    && fldKey.containsKey(CsdClient.getLifeCycle())

              }
          }
        }
```

Comment: "need perfect approach" - why? If your code does what it should do what else do you want?

Comment: I am not sure how to move forward after that

Comment: A few notes though: 1) a map should never have a null key (at least not the standard maps) thus `fldKey!= null` is unnecessary 2) `fldKey.equalsIgnoreCase("")´ - what exactly do you want to check for here? An empty string doesn't have any case and you'd check for empty keys only anyway 3) `fldKey.containsKey(...)` that's not a method that can be called on a string.

Comment: It's hard to help more without knowing how you've represented your data in code and what exactly you need. One note though: I hope your data is represented by proper objects instead of nested maps and collections only.

Comment: i want condition that would check for a key and then fetch that number associated to that key.

Comment: Well, how about a simple `map.get(key)` and taking the number from the returned object?

Comment: Yes,I need to fetch numbers based on group key

Comment: I also need to iterate the map

Comment: As I already wrote, without knowing more it is really hard to help more. Also what hinders you from iterating the map? And why would you need to do this in the first place? Please add that information to your question instead of a comment - we don't want to piece it together. The more effort _you_ put into your question the more likely will people be willing and able to help.

Comment: What more information would be needed? I can provide

Comment: Think about what you'd need to help: the requirements, relevant code you've written (e.g. what the maps actually look like), what you need, where exactly you're failing and why (lack of knowledge/understanding, errors in code etc.)...

Comment: I still don’t understand what you’re trying to do.  Why is `skillsValueMap.get(key)` not sufficient?